# Gitlab Container Registry missing image Tags

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry, gitlab-ce

Hello everyone I hope you're doing okay !
I'm facing a problem in gitlab-**ce**

**Problem :**

> can't see images tags after migrating gitlab to a new host
>
> can't login to my registry using docker login
> http://gitlab.examlple.com:5005

returns :

`Error response from daemon: Get "https://gitlab.example.com:5005/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`

**Orginal Instance :**

[My original Gitlab instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnqFu.png)

**New Instance**

[My new Gitlab instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMmP7.png)

**Migration Type:**

> backup the original gitlab and restore it in the new Instance

**Changes Made :**

- changed the external_url in gitlab.rb to a new one (i didn't keep the ip adress)
- changed registry_url

i hope someone can help me with this issue

thank you all in advance

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Hi ossama assaghir, In undid you first edit which is against the concept of StackOverflow and explained why in a comment. You seem to insist on undoing that. Do you need help with understanding why you should not? Feel free to ask me in a comment here. Just include "@Yunnosch" and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem was :**

The Port 5005 wasn't Opened in my new Instance, Gitlab was trying to access the registry but it couldn't

**Solution :**

Open port 5005

**Using RHEL 7**

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5005/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing Gitlab from Omnimbus Repository? It seems like you do not follow the full document because it will ask you to issue or provide SSL certificate. It's not a good practice nowadays if you are still using HTTP instead of HTTPS but it's a good point to start if you don't need to care much about security as your registry password may be captured easily by attackers.

To enable HTTP protocol, can you try to disable `redirect_http_to_https`. Besides, if your new Gitlab is the latest version, it should be `registry_external_url` but not `registry_url` anymore.

```
registry_external_url 'http://registry-gitlab.example.com'
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
```